# How can I enable hardware virtualization when it has been locked in my Dell Vostro 220 PC?

Tags: bios, hardware-virtualization

I need help in unlocking my Dell Vostro 220 hardware virtualization.

I ran SecurAble and it gave me the results below:

> 64-bit Maximum Word Length
>
> Hardware D.E.P --- YES
>
> Hardware Virtualization --- Locked Off

My Processor is the Intel Dual Core E5200 @ 2.5 GHz. I want to have the hardware virtualization ON for improved virtualization by VMWare, VirtualBox, etc.

Can anyone help me safely achieve this?

Motherboard Manufacturer and Model, Dell -- Dont know much, but in the CMOS Setup it said on the Top:

> CMOS Setup Utility (c) 1985-2008 American Megatrends Inc.
>
> - System Info: Vostro 220 Series
> - Bios Revision : 1.30 6/22/2010
> - Bios Type : Dont know
> - Bios SLIC : Dont know
> - Bios File Name: Vx20-130.EXE

further BIOS info [here.](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=R272986)

How do I unlock my BIOS so that I can access the VHD settings that I can't seem to find?

Comment: Enter the bios (F2) and enable hardware VT.

Answer (score 1):

Your processor doesn't support VT-x instructions, as per [Intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/spec/slay7). So it doesn't have Hardware Virtualization support.