# Is virtualization available on my Dell Inspiron 560 Desktop?

Tags: bios, dell-inspiron, hardware-virtualization

I want to enable virtualization on my Dell Inspiron 560 with an Intel Pentium Dual-Core E6700 CPU, but I don't know if it's possible. I've heard about it not being in the BIOS (or at least hidden), and I don't want to install third party software.

Thanks in advance!

**[SOLVED!]** As it turns out, I needed to go into a subcategory for my CPU settings, which contained virtualization. I am now able to run 64-bit virtual machines. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: If there is no option to enable it in the firmware then it Cannot be enabled

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/371166/how-can-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-when-it-has-been-locked-in-my-dell-vost?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) is [available for Pentium E6700](http://ark.intel.com/products/42809/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E6700-2M-Cache-3_20-GHz-1066-FSB). It is [disabled by default by Dell](http://www.manualguru.com/dell/inspiron-560/service-manual/page-32) see paragraph on Advanced BIOS Features.

Search for [Advanced tab in your BIOS settings](http://amiduos.com/support/knowledge-base/article/enabling-virtualization-technology-in-dell-systems) and enable the virtualisation there. If you cannot allocate the Advanced tab in your BIOS menu then try the steps described in this [Super User thread](https://superuser.com/questions/853994/enabling-intel-vt-x-virtualization-with-a-dell-bios).

You also need to manually enable virtualization in your OS. You did not mention which Windows version are you on, but these instructions apply both for Windows 7, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. Follow this Microsoft guide on how to [enable Hyper-V](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_install) on your machine.

Comment: Thanks! Nice to know I can do this. I made an operating system in 64bit and need to test it in a VM.

Comment: I've just updated my answer so you might want to check if these settings are configured properly as well.

Comment: I use Windows 7 so it should work.

Comment: I just skimmed through the advanced tab and it isn't there. What should i do now?

Comment: Have you tried to enable the Hyper-V through Windows itself?

Comment: I checked my windows features and it wasn't there.

Comment: You might need to [download and install the RSAT tools for Windows 7](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/schadinio/2010/07/09/installing-hyper-v-manager-on-windows-7/) in order for Hyper-V to appear on software features list.